# Duda al modificar documento WORD desde Java

Tags: java, apache-poi, ms-word

necesito modificar unas plantillas que están en formato **.doc** desde **Java**, es decir, que mediante código detecto ciertas palabras del documento las cuales utilizo como "variables" para después modificarlas por las que yo le pase.
He conseguido mediante la librería **POI**, acceder a dicho documento, separar por párrafos, detectar donde se encuentra dicha palabra a modificar, y cambiarla pero a nivel de código (no la consigo modificar en el documento word).
Os dejo el código que llevo hasta ahora resumido, agradecería mucho si alguien me puede ayudar a sacar esa parte que me falta.
Gracias de antemano.

```
package PruebasWord;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import org.apache.poi.hwpf.HWPFDocument;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Paragraph;
import org.apache.poi.hwpf.usermodel.Range;
import org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem;

//ESTO LEE Y BUSCA PALABRAS O CONTENIDO POR LINEAS DENTRO DE UN ARCHIVO CON FORMATO DETERMINADO 
//( COMO PUEDE SER UN WORD, PERO GUARDADO EN VERSION .doc )


public class prueba2 {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException  {  

        //RUTA DONDE SE ENCUENTRA EL DOCUMENTO .doc
        String fileName = "C:\\Datos\\Hola.doc";
        //STRING QUE ALMACENARA EL CONTENIDO DE CADA PARRAFO DEL DOCUMENTO
        String linea = "";

        InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fileName);  
        POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);  
        HWPFDocument doc = new HWPFDocument(fs);  


        //ASIGNA A LA VARIABLE range COMO VALOR EL RANGO DEL DOCUMENTO
        Range range = doc.getRange();

        //IMPRIME POR CONSOLA EL CONTENIDO DEL DOCUMENTO
        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentText());
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        //IMPRIME POR CONSOLA NUMERO DE PARRAFOS
        System.out.println(range.numParagraphs());
        System.out.println("---------------------------");

        //BUCLE RECORRE EL DOCUMENTO POR PARRAFOS
        for (int i=0; i<range.numParagraphs(); i++) {
            //CREA EL PARRAFO DEL DOCUMENTO
            Paragraph par = range.getParagraph(i);
            //PASAMOS EL PARRAFO EN EL QUE NOS ENCONTRAMOS A UN STRING (linea)
            linea = par.text().toString();


            //IMPRIME EL CONTENIDO DEL PARRAFO
            System.out.println(linea);

            //DEVUELVE true SI LA PALABRA (Hola) SE ENCUENTRA DENTRO DEL PARRAFO
            System.out.println(linea.indexOf("Hola") >= 0);

            //SI EL PARRAFO CONTIENE (Hola) INDICA QUE AHÍ ESTÁ Y QUE CAMBIARÁ
            if(par.text().toString().indexOf("Hola") >= 0) {
                System.out.print("          Aquí Cambiará!! --> ");

            } 

            //REEMPLAZA (SI CONTIENE) LA PALABRA (Hola) DE DICHO PARRAFO, POR LA PALABRA (Cambio)
            par.replaceText("Hola", "Cambio");
            //DEBE IMPRIMIR POR PANTALLA EL PARRAFO MODIFICADO SI SE DIO EL CASO..
            System.out.println(par.text().toString());

        } // fin for

      //VOLVEMOS A IMPRIMIR EL DOCUMENTO POR CONSOLA Y COMPROBAMOS QUE SE HA MODIFICADO
        System.out.println("---------------------------");
        System.out.println(doc.getDocumentText().toString());

    } //fin main

}
```

Comment: y no deberias al final escribir el documento con [`doc.write(File)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hwpf/HWPFDocument.html#write-java.io.File-) ?

Comment: Si me supongo que tendre que utilizar un FileOutputStream para escribir despues y tambien lo he probado, el caso es que no se exactamente como decir que me modifique esa cadena de caracteres por la que yo le doy..

Comment: @JavierSanchezMSM te ha dado algun error con las pruebas que has hecho?

Comment: ¿qué versión del POI utilizas? Estoy también haciendo pruebas de lectura de docx y reparé en tú cuestión que es más o menos lo que quiero conseguir. He intentado ver que le ocurre a tú código, pero no funcionó. Tengo POI 3.17. A ver si se consigue algo!